# celery + django - how to write task state to database

Tags: django, celery

I'm running Celery with Django and RabbitMQ and want to see the task states in the database table. Unfortunately no entries are written into the table djcelery_taskstate and I can't figure out why.

My settings:

```
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'

CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = True

CELERY_IMPORTS = ("project_management.tasks", "accounting.tasks", "time_tracking.tasks", )
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

My Task:

```
class TestTask(Task):

    def run(self, po_id):
        self.update_state(state=states.STARTED, meta={'total': 0, 'done': False})
        #do something..
        self.update_state(state=states.SUCCESS, meta={'total': 100, 'done': True})
```

I'm starting the task as follows in a view:

```
TestTask.apply_async(args=[], kwargs={})
```

I'm starting celery workers as follows.

```
python manage.py celeryd -v 1 -B -s celery -E -l INFO
```

Console gives me the following output:

```
[2013-05-19 11:10:03,774: INFO/MainProcess] Task accounting.tasks.TestTask[5463b2ed-0eba-451d-b828-7a89fcd36348] succeeded in 0.0538640022278s: None
```

Any idea what is wrong with my setup?

Comment: Are you also running `python manage.py celerycam`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start up the [snapshot camera](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/release21-maint/userguide/monitoring.html#starting-the-monitor) as well in order to see the results in the database.

```
python manage.py celerycam
```

Once you have that running, you will be able to see entries in the `djcelery` tables.