# Save the Celery task in DB- Django

Tags: python, django, celery, djcelery

I'm referring to [Django Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) documents.

I created `celery.py` in my `proj/proj` just as the document said. and then included `__init__.py`

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')
app = Celery('proj')
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',
)
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

I installed `pip install django-celery` , then migrated `python manage.py migrate djcelery`
It made some of the tables in my DB.

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task
import requests
import json

@shared_task
def post_notification(data,url):
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

After that I called my task in my views as

```
task = post_notification.delay(data,url)
print task.id #it prints an id
print task.status # prints PENDING
```

But nothing gets logged into any of my tables.

I've read my threads on SO,[Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633107/celery-django-how-to-write-task-state-to-database?rq=1)  , [Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672987/how-to-properly-configure-djcelery-results-backend-to-database) and many more given on these threads, but nothing happens.

**It provides me the ID & status of the task but how do I save the task in the DB?** Usually it should get logged into `celery_taskmeta`, but there's nothing in there.

Though the task gets execute but I want to save the task in  DB as well. How can I do it? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You shouldn't evaluate `app.conf` like that (`app.conf.update`), since it will load the django settings module early.  You should set the `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` setting in your settings.py.  Also did you remember to add `djcelery` to INSTALLED_APPS?  If you want to set the backend as a default outside of your settings then you can use `app = Celery(..., backend='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend`).   Note that the results are only updated when the worker writes the RETRY/FAILURE/SUCCESS states, the PENDING state is not saved to the db, instead all unknown ids will be PENDING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following in `settings.py` file

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost//'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

And start the worker.

Answer (score 0):

try this in celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
from celery.schedules import crontab

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app_name.dev_settings')

app = Celery('app_name')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app.conf.CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',
)
```

Comment: @user1162512 hope it wil sove your problem

Comment: No. Still no effect. BTW is it `app_name.dev_settings` or only `app_name.settings` without `dev`?

Comment: Tried both. No effect.

Comment: ohh its settings and app_name means ur app_name

Comment: Is it app name or project_name?

Comment: have u configured ur app_name in installed_apps in django setting file the same app_name should be here

Comment: Yes, I've configured my app in installed apps. Also when I'll write `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app_name.settings')` , there'll no file `settings` under my `app`. So how can I add `app_name`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be project_name?

Comment: I've tried with both `project_name` and `app_name`, doesn't works in any case? Just in case, do I need to start the celery worked using `celery -A project_name  worker -l info` or do Django starts the worker itself?

Comment: try this also in setting file
BROKER_URL= 'amqp://localhost:6379'